# How to scale Flutter Gridview content for different screen sizes

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-layout

I am trying to use a grid view to display a grid of 2x5 cards.
The Gridview is inside a column layout as shown here.
[image]

Now when I run this code for different device sizes, the gridview card size does not scale effectively as I am assuming my “childAspectRatio: 3 / 1.6,” does not work due to different screen proportions.

This is how I get a scrolling in device with wider screen size.
No scroll on longer screen.

[image]

and, scroll on wider screen

[image]

So I was wondering if there is a workaround to fix this?
Can I use something other than childAspectRatio?

My Gridview parameters look like this:

```
child: GridView.count(
crossAxisCount: 2,
mainAxisSpacing: 0,
crossAxisSpacing: 0,
childAspectRatio: 3 / 1.6,
```

Update:
Additional code as requested.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'level_slider_carousel.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:xactly/utils/styles.dart';
import 'package:smooth_page_indicator/smooth_page_indicator.dart';
import 'package:xactly/utils/size_config.dart';

class GameHome extends StatefulWidget {
  createState() {
    return GameHomePage();
  }
}

class GameHomePage extends State<GameHome> {
final PageController _pageController = new PageController();
int pCount = 0;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 4,
          child: Container(
            //Header code here
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 23,
          child: PageView(
            controller: _pageController,
            onPageChanged: _onPageChanged,
            children: [
              // Just duplicating the same pages to create multi-page slider
              new LevelSlider(),
              new LevelSlider(),
              new LevelSlider(),
              new LevelSlider(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 5,
          child: Container(
            // Footer code here
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  floatingActionButton: Container(
    height: 8 * SizeConfig.textMultiplier,
    width: 8 * SizeConfig.textMultiplier,
    child: FittedBox(
      // Button code here
    ),
  ),
  floatingActionButtonLocation: 
FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
);
 }
    }


   class LevelSlider extends StatelessWidget { 
final int level; 
LevelSlider({this.level});
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
String t;
return Scaffold(
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
      left: 10,
      right: 10,
    ),
    child: GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      mainAxisSpacing: 0,
      crossAxisSpacing: 0,
      childAspectRatio: 3 / 1.6,
      children: List.generate(
        10,
        (index) {
          switch (index) {
            case 0:
              t = 'One';
              break;
            case 1:
              t = 'Two';
              break;
            case 2:
              t = 'Three';
              break;
            case 3:
              t = 'Four';
              break;
            case 4:
              t = 'Five';
              break;
            case 5:
              t = 'Six';
              break;
            case 6:
              t = 'Seven';
              break;
            case 7:
              t = 'Eight';
              break;
            case 8:
              t = 'Nine';
              break;
            case 9:
              t = 'Ten';
              break;
          }
          return new Card(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            ),
            elevation: 1.0,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Card $index clicked');
              },
              child: new Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                ),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    // Code for stuff inside cards
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: How about using responsive widgets plugin to fit in every screen size? https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_widgets/

Answer (score 0):

please send the full code. from starting last or see the example code here
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this question is still looking to be answered, but I'll throw this out there.

If I were you, I'd use a LayoutBuilder, or use some MediaQuery for the sizing of the widgets.